# Reading an absolute encoder with gray code output

Tags: arduino, sensors, arduino-c++

I have an absolute encoder(Hengstler AD36) that gives 12 bit position value with gray code. I am trying to convert that value to decimal, I mean in degrees 0 to 360.

I have the 12 bit value in gray code by using Arduino.I have read the Arduino port and converted it in Python, but I need to do it in Arduino.  But, I couldn't convert it to any meaningful numbers in Arduino.

```
///Pin setup for the Sensor
const int CLOCK_PIN = 18;
const int DATA_PIN = 19;
const int DATA_PIN2 = 17;
///12-bit sensor
const int BIT_COUNT = 12;

void setup() {
  //setup our pins
  pinMode(DATA_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(CLOCK_PIN, OUTPUT);
  //give some default values
  digitalWrite(CLOCK_PIN, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  unsigned long reading1 = readPosition1();
  Serial.print(reading1,BIN);
  Serial.print(",");
  delay(50);
}

//read the current angular position
int readPosition1() {
  unsigned long sample1 = shiftIn(DATA_PIN, CLOCK_PIN, BIT_COUNT);

  delayMicroseconds(25);  // delay for clock
  return sample1;
  }


//read in a byte of data from the digital input of the board.
unsigned long shiftIn(const int data_pin, const int clock_pin, const int bit_count) {
  unsigned long data = 0;

  for (int i=0; i<bit_count; i++) {
    data <<= 1;
    digitalWrite(clock_pin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(1);
    digitalWrite(clock_pin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(1);

    data |= digitalRead(data_pin);
  }

  return data;
}
```

How can I convert **data** to decimal (0 to 360 degrees)?

The main problem that I couldn't solve, I found some functions that convert gray code to binary, then it is easy to convert it to decimal. However, these functions take input as string or int, and I have no idea about converting **data** value to **int**.

*Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.*

Comment: have you tried encoder library in the Arduino? https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/encoder  . Can post the code you did in python? converting shouldn't be difficult

Comment: I could not find anything useful for me in encoder library.
`def gray_to_binary(n):
    """Convert Gray codeword to binary and return it."""
    n = int(n, 2) # convert to int 
    mask = n
          while mask != 0:
        mask >>= 1
        n ^= mask
 
    return n

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM8',baudrate=9600,timeout=1)
print('opened')
s = [0]
print('initialized')
i=0
print('loop starts')

for i in range(0,1000):
    s = ser.readline()
    a = s.decode("utf-8")
    x = a.split(",")
    reading1 = gray_to_binary(x[0])*0.087;    
ser.close()`

Comment: if reading1 = gray_to_binary(x[0])*0.087; can give you decimal reading. then just add the gray_to_binary function inside arduino. or if you feel not so sure, you can also use the library to do so

Comment: But, this code works for Python, actually gray_to_binary(x[0])*0.087 gives me decimal value-what I want-, how can I insert it this Python code into Arduino ?

Comment: you are telling me that you dont know how to convert a 6 line python code into arudino C++?  all bit wise operation is the same.  int(n, 2) instead for BIN to int. you can directly read as int in Arduino.   add a sample of readPosition1() output. list of them. and a list of corresponding output for angle. I`ll help you prep this if you feel it is too hard

Comment: This is the sample output of the Arduino when I read it from Raspberry b'100001101010,0\n'   Using decode utf8 works in Python but I really don't know how to use it in Arduino. 2 sensor data is seperated with comma in the output

Comment: I mean all I need is b'100001101010,0\n' is converted to 100001101010,0 with python .decode("utf-8") method. What can does the same thing Arduino platform ? Thanks for your comments, but I really did not understand

Comment: the sample1 variable is already in 100001101010 formats that you want. You can verify it by Serial.println(reading1);   the output should be equivalent to 100001101010 . its your action of Serial.print(reading1,BIN); makes it the other way.